# Can "interesting" be used anything else other than adjective?

Tags: grammar

"It was an interesting movie."  Any specific rule that the word INTERESTING ends with ing. Can this word be used as a participle or a gerund phrase?

Comment: The gerund-participle form "Interesting" is either a verb, as in "Ed was interesting me with his tales", or an adjective as in "Ed's stories were very interesting".

Answer (score 2):

There is a verb "to interest".  It is not often used as a participle or gerund, but it is possible:

> The first stage in teaching maths is interesting your student in the subject.

However this is a garden path sentence. The use of the gerund is unusual and so the brain parses "interesting" as an adjective, then has to back up.  I would rephrase as "getting your student interested".

Participle use is also possible

> Flower arranging is interesting me at the moment.
>   Interesting her with the promise of large profits, the conman deceived the woman.

It is possible, but perhaps not a good idea.